# Inequality in difference of square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I think this inequality is true and I'm trying to prove it:

For real, non-negative $a$ and $b$

$$\lvert \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\rvert \le \lvert \sqrt{a - b} \rvert$$

Closest thing I've found is equation

$$\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a + b + \sqrt{4ab}}$$

But this breaks if I set $b$ to $-b$ because then you're taking the root of a negative.

Does anyone have a proof of this, or a more general result that implies this?

Comment: If $a < b$ then $|\sqrt {a-b}|$ does not exist and this is not true.

Comment: "But this breaks if I set b to −b " why would you do that?  the question specifically says $b$ is positive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you wrote $\sqrt{a-b}$, I suppose $a\ge b$. Then
$|\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}|^2\le|\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}||\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}|=a-b$. Take square roots on both sides and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true if $a < b$.  If $a < b $ then $a -b < 0$ and $\sqrt{a-b}$ does not exist and $|\sqrt{a-b}|$ does not exist.  And so it is not true that $|\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}| \le |\sqrt{a-b}|$.

I *think* what you meant was to prove $|\sqrt{a} -\sqrt{b}| \le \sqrt{|a - b|}$ which is true.

Notice: $\min (a,b) \le \sqrt{ab}\le \max(a,b)$.  Why? If $c = \min (a,b)$ and $d = \max(a,b)$ then $c =\sqrt{c\cdot c}\le \sqrt{c\cdot d}(=\sqrt{ab})\le \sqrt{d\cdot d} = d$.

So.  Letting $c = \min(a,b)$ and $d=\max(a,b)$ we have

$|\sqrt a-\sqrt b|^2 = (\sqrt{d} - \sqrt{x})^2 = d  -2\sqrt{cd} + c\le d - 2c+c = d-c= |a-b|$.

And as we are dealing with non-negative values it follows

$\sqrt {|\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}|^2}\le \sqrt{|a-b|}$ or

$|\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}|^2 \le |a-b|$

.....

Although an easier way to do it is if we don't get bogged down in absolute values; they are only there to assure to take the positive values anyway.

For any $0 \le  b\le a$ then

$\sqrt a - \sqrt b \le \sqrt{a-b} \iff$

$(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2 \le (\sqrt{a-b})^2 \iff$

$a -2\sqrt{ab} + b \le a -b\iff$

$b \le \sqrt{ab}$ and as $b < a$ it follow $b = \sqrt{b^2}\le \sqrt{ab}$.

....

Or directly:

$\sqrt{a - b} = \sqrt{a -2b + b}=\sqrt{a -2\sqrt{b}\sqrt{b} + b} \ge \sqrt{a - 2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} + b}=\sqrt{(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2} = \sqrt a - \sqrt b$.

Comment: In the 7th row it should be c instead of x in one place

Answer (score 1):

$a\ge b\ge 0$ then
$$
\\|\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}|\le|\sqrt{a-b}| <=>
\\\sqrt{a}\le \sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a-b}<=>
\\a\le b+a-b+2\sqrt{b(a-b)}<=>
\\\sqrt{b(a-b)}\ge0
$$

Comment: Formatting tip: Type `$\implies$` to obtain $\implies$ and `$\iff$` to obtain $\iff$.