# Prove that $\left |\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{[tn]}X_i-\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{[tn]}} \sum_{i=1}^{[tn]}X_i\right |\overset{n}{\to}0$ in probability

Tags: probability-theory

> As the title states, I would like to prove that
>
> $$\left | \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor tn \rfloor }X_i  - \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\lfloor tn \rfloor}} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor tn \rfloor}X_i \right |$$
>
> converges to zero, with $n $, in probability. Here $X_i $ are independent random variables with zero mean and second moment equal to one. $\lfloor x \rfloor $ denotes the floor function and $t $ is a positive real number.

---

My first thought was that

$$\left | \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor tn \rfloor}X_i  - \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\lfloor tn \rfloor}} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor tn \rfloor}X_i \right |=\left |\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor tn \rfloor}X_i \right |\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}   - \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\lfloor tn \rfloor}} \right |$$

Where $\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}   - \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\lfloor tn \rfloor}} \right | \overset {n } {\to } 0 $. But does it converge sufficiently fast so that the product with $\left |\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor tn \rfloor}X_i \right | $ converges to zero?

Most grateful for any help provided!

Comment: Isn't it just equal to zero? $$\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{nk}}=\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k}\cdot \sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: sorry, will have to edit the post!

Comment: While you are at it, tell us what $X_i$ is.

Comment: Just work with $tn -1 \le \lfloor tn \rfloor \le tn$ to argue that $|\sqrt{t/\lfloor tn \rfloor} - 1/\sqrt{n}| = O(t^{-1} n^{-3/2})$ (this should be intuitive if you think of the derivative of $x^{-1/2}$). This is more than enough to kill the $|\sum_{i \le tn} X_i |$ term in probability - you can argue via Tchebycheff. In fact, due to the bounded second moment, this will also kill it almost surely, since $\sum_{i \le tn} |X_i|/tn$ will be $O(1)$ a.s.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I believe I got a proof following your comment. Could you please have a look at it? Also have would one show that $\sum_{i \le tn } |X_i|/tn $ is $\mathcal {O } (1)$? Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt to an answer using the points from stochasticboy321's comment above.

We will try to apply Chebyshev's inequality which in our case states, since the variance of $\sum_{i=1 } ^{\lfloor nt \rfloor } X_i$ is $\lfloor nt \rfloor$, that

$$P[|\sum_{i=1 } ^{\lfloor nt \rfloor } X_i | \ge \epsilon \sqrt{\lfloor nt \rfloor}] \le \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}, \ \epsilon>0$$

for which is would be sufficient to show that, for some $n_0 $ onwards,

$$\left | \sqrt {\frac{t}{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}   - \frac{1}{\sqrt {n}}  \right |  \le \left | \frac{1}{tn} \right |$$

since then we would have [for $n \ge n_0 $]

$$P[|\sum_{i=1 } ^{\lfloor nt \rfloor } X_i |\left | \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\lfloor nt \rfloor}} \right | \ge \epsilon ] \le P[|\sum_{i=1 } ^{\lfloor nt \rfloor } X_i |\left | \frac{1}{\lfloor tn \rfloor} \right | \ge \epsilon ] \le \frac{1}{\epsilon^2 \lfloor tn \rfloor} \overset {n } {\to}  0$$

---

**Attempt to show that $ \left | \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\lfloor nt \rfloor}} \right | = \mathcal{O}(t^{-1 } n^{-3/2 })$:**

From the inequality $ nt -1 < \lfloor nt \rfloor  \le nt $ we get

$$\frac{1}{nt} \le \frac{1}{\lfloor nt \rfloor} < \frac{1}{nt-1} \implies \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{t}{\lfloor nt \rfloor} < \frac{t}{nt-1}=\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n(nt-1)}$$

and since $0 \le a \le b < c \implies b-a \le c-a $ we get

$$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{t}{\lfloor nt \rfloor} \le \left (\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n(nt-1)}\right ) - \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n(nt-1)}$$

and thus

$$\left |\frac{t}{\lfloor nt \rfloor}  - \frac{1}{n} \right | \le \left | \frac{1}{n(nt-1)} \right |$$

Since $|\sqrt{a} -  \sqrt{b}| \le \sqrt{|a-b|}$ holds for any two non negative numbers [see eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986173/inequality-in-difference-of-square-roots)] we get the inequality.

$$\left | \sqrt {\frac{t}{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}   - \frac{1}{\sqrt {n}}  \right | \le \left | \frac{1}{\sqrt {n(nt-1)}} \right |$$

**I don't think it is true that**

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {n(nt-1)} } = \mathcal{O}(t^{-1 } n^{-3/2})$$

but I do believe we have that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {n(nt-1)} } = \mathcal{O}(t^{-1 } n^{-1})$$

which as noted above would be sufficient.

---

Any comment would be much appreciated!

Comment: The $t^{-1}n^{-3/2}$ upper bound is true:

$$ \sqrt\frac{t}{tn - 1 } - \sqrt\frac{1}{n} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot \left( \sqrt{\frac{t}{t - 1/n}} -1\right) = \sqrt\frac{1}{n}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-1/tn}} - 1 \right)$$

Intuitively, the term in the parentheses is $1/tn$ times the derivative of $1/\sqrt{x}$ at $1$ for $n\gg 1,$ i.e. the whole thing is $O(t^{-1} n^{-3/2})$. Non-asymptotically, you can prove straightforwardly that for $0<z < \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2},$ $1/\sqrt{1-z}  \le 1+ z,$ giving a bound on the above of $ t^{-1}n^{-3/2}$ for all $n > 2/t$.

Comment: The rest looks fine.